# Upload file from JS to S3

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3

I have a vue javascript application. I want to upload a file to an S3 bucket - using quite plain Js my current state is:

```
async function onFileChange(event) {
   let formData = new FormData();           
   const files = event.target.files || event.dataTransfer.files;
   const package_file = files[0].name;
   formData.set("package_file", files[0]);

   const [s3_data, ] = await wrapAsync(createS3Url, [{"package_file" : package_file}]);

   const url = s3_data.data.s3_package_url.url;
   const data = s3_data.data.s3_package_url.fields;

   for (const key in data) {
       formData.set(key, data[key]);
   }

   await fetch(url, {
      method: "POST", 
      body: formData,
   });    
}
```

The call to (not shown) function `createS3Url()` seems to work, I get a presigned url and a list of settings back. But when I actually try to post this to s3 with `fetch(url, ...)` it fails on the S3 side. My feeling is that the problem is with the `body` passed to the `fetch()` call? I have tried some variations - right now the error message from S3 is:

```
<Error><Code>MaxPostPreDataLengthExceeded</Code><Message>Your POST request fields preceeding the upload file was too large.</Message><MaxPostPreDataLengthBytes>20480</MaxPostPreDataLengthBytes><RequestId>NC4J0JQDNHAPR7J8</RequestId><HostId>5QOk1Ran5Ac+mORoqUo5Ommmu2kqtsIuEgRXQSKGx8jwuIqf0auAdLkJaQcaI47pb005mZyrIK8=</HostId></Error>
```

There is also a CORS error message:

```
POST https://storagestack-softwarepackages06fbedb7-1dmnxdlbs1kjh.s3.amazonaws.com/
CORS Missing Allow Origin
```

I am currently running on localhost. Have not done anything in particular on my localhost - or on the s3 end in order to support CORS?

Update: I have now found out that:

1. The key pointing to the file content must be exactly `file`.
2. The `file` element must be the last added to the `FormData` instance.

Observing these two points I get further, but now there is a permission problem of some sort.

Comment: Did you check by uploading a file which is smaller and follows the file limit? From error it looks like you need to update the post data limit.

Comment: Observe that the size related error is not about the file - but the other POST fields. That said I have tried with a very small file - same problem.

Comment: Ehh - I did eventually manage to get it work, but ohh man it was a fight. I think the final thing which solved it for me was that i *removed* the "Authorized" header which was originally part of the POST request (that was added by my framework). Good luck!